# How to get columns out of a List of Views in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The goal is to get a pre-made View from a DB2 Database and display the content on a webpage.

The application runs on a JBoss Server and the data comes from a DB2 System. I am already able to print out the needed data on my console and all drivers are installed/deployed.

---

I have a datatable like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="portview" value="#{vb.pvlist}" stickyHeader="true"
        stickyTopAt=".layout-topbar">
        <f:facet name="header">PortView</f:facet>

        <p:column headerText="Instance">
            <h:outputText value="#{vb.getPVInst}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Port">
            <h:outputText value="#{vb.getPVPort}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Port Comment">
            <h:outputText value="#{vb.getPVPortC}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Server">
            <h:outputText value="#{vb.getPVServer}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

My bean is this:

```
@ManagedBean(value = "vb")
@RequestScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {

    private List<PortView> pvlist;

    @Inject
    private ViewHandler vh;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setPVList(vh.getPortViewList());
    }

    public List<PortView> getPVList() {
        return pvlist;
    }

    public void setPVList(List<PortView> pvlist) {
        this.pvlist = pvlist;
    }

    public String getPVInst() {
        return pvlist.get(1).getInstance();
    }
    // getters for other cols
```

My DB Handler (View Handler) looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class ViewHandler {

    //EntityManager related stuff

    public void test() {
        TypedQuery<PortView> pvquery = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM PortView v", PortView.class);

        List<PortView> pvlist = pvquery.getResultList();

        for (PortView pv : pvlist) {
            System.out.println(pv.getInstance() + "|" + pv.getPort() + "|" + pv.getPort_comment() + "|" + pv.getServer());
        }
    }

    public List<PortView> getPortViewList() {
        List<PortView> pvlist = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM PortView v", PortView.class).getResultList();
        return pvlist;
    }
}
```

---

Q: How do I get the contents of the column into the datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your variable "portview" (as defined in the dataTable) in your columns.
like that:

```
<p:column headerText="Instance">
     <h:outputText value="#{portview.instance}" />
</p:column>
```

You don't need those getters for the columns in your bean.

Comment: If I do as you say, the webpage shows "No records found.".

Comment: then your list is empty ;-)
You should debug, to see, if its initialized correctly.